# What is the equivalent of eksctl option "--alb-ingress-access" in a config file?

Tags: kubernetes

I read [How to run Serverless Kubernetes: AWS EKS on Fargate](https://www.learnaws.org/2019/12/16/running-eks-on-aws-fargate/), and am wondering what the equivalent option for `--alb-ingress-access` is in a config schema shown in [Config file schema](https://eksctl.io/usage/schema/#managedNodeGroups-iam-withAddonPolicies-albIngress)? At least it's not obvious to me. I even created a sample cluster and printed out the info and didn't see it there.

```
$ eksctl create cluster \
    --name ingress-sample \
    --version 1.19 \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --fargate \
    --alb-ingress-access
$ eksctl get cluster --name ingress-sample -o yaml
- Arn: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:0123456789:cluster/ingress-sample
  CertificateAuthority:
    Data: <redacted>
  ClientRequestToken: null
  CreatedAt: "2021-02-19T00:44:27.976Z"
  EncryptionConfig: null
  Endpoint: https://<redacted>.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  Identity:
    Oidc:
      Issuer: https://oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/redacted
  KubernetesNetworkConfig:
    ServiceIpv4Cidr: 10.100.0.0/16
  Logging:
    ClusterLogging:
    - Enabled: false
      Types:
      - api
      - audit
      - authenticator
      - controllerManager
      - scheduler
  Name: ingress-sample
  PlatformVersion: eks.1
  ResourcesVpcConfig:
    ClusterSecurityGroupId: sg-xxxxxx
    EndpointPrivateAccess: false
    EndpointPublicAccess: true
    PublicAccessCidrs:
    - 0.0.0.0/0
    SecurityGroupIds:
    - sg-xxxxxx
    SubnetIds:
    - subnet-111111
    - subnet-222222
    - subnet-333333
    - subnet-444444
    VpcId: vpc-xxxxxx
  RoleArn: arn:aws:iam::0123456789:role/eksctl-ingress-sample-cluster-ServiceRole-D0X7QCIRBSDN
  Status: ACTIVE
  Tags: {}
  Version: "1.19"
```

**UPDATE**: Hmmm, maybe

```
$ eksctl create cluster --alb-ingress-access -f config.yaml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep this worked, or at least I didn't get an error

```
    $ eksctl create cluster --alb-ingress-access -f config.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `iam` key in your node groups.

```
    iam:
      withAddonPolicies:
        albIngress: true
```

See an example here: [23-kubeflow-spot-instance.yaml](https://github.com/eksctl-io/eksctl/blob/v0.149.0/examples/23-kubeflow-spot-instance.yaml#L57)